# Is "the" required here?

Tags: grammar, articles

Should I use *the* or not:

> The second level is (the) network layer.

Comment: Hi Malik! Please provide more context. Right now it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you asking if you should use the word "the" in this context?

Comment: Can you provide an example that is a complete sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're speaking of computer networking, the required form in a sentence is **the network layer**.  You will find many examples of good usage (including bare "Network Layer" for headings) in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ***the*** is required in the example sentence you gave.

Another example:

**The network layer is layer three in the OSI model.**